# Tesseract doesn't recognize clean image

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I have two images from a game and would like to recognize the number on them.

I'm using the newest tesseract version (tesseract v5.2.0.20220708) for windows 10.

So the raw image looks like this:

[image]

After processing it with the code below I get this result, which looks pretty good:

[image]

Tesseract recognizes this pretty accurately, but when the number in the image is smaller like in this raw image:

[image]

or rather the cleaned version of this

[image]

For this image, it doesn't recognize anything and I'm not sure why.

This code I use for cleaning the image

```py
def _prepare_image_for_ocr(img, lower_val, upper_val):
    # Create a mask so all non white pixels get "removed"
    hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
    white_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_image, lower_val, upper_val)

    # Use a little bit of morphology to clean the mask
    # Set kernel (structuring element) size
    kernel_size = 3
    # Set morph operation iterations
    op_iterations = 1
    # Get the structuring element
    morph_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernel_size, op_iterations))
    # Perform closing and return
    return cv2.morphologyEx(white_mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN,morph_kernel, None, None, op_iterations, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101)

# Lower and upper val for the first image
lower_val = np.array([30, 30, 30])
upper_val = np.array([255, 255, 255])

# upper val for the second image which needs a bit different values
# upper_val = np.array([230, 230, 230])

# cropped_image is the input RGB image

# Convert to the gray-scale
gry = cv2.cvtColor(cropped_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

white_mask = _prepare_image_for_ocr(cropped_image, lower_val, upper_val)

# Invert the gray image so we can use it with the mask
inverted_gray = (255 - gry)

# Use the inverted gray image with the white mask to get the white pixels
color_mask = cv2.add(inverted_gray, white_mask)

# blur
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(color_mask, (0, 0), sigmaX=33, sigmaY=33)

# divide
divide = cv2.divide(color_mask, blur, scale=255)

# Binarize the image
_, binarized_gray = cv2.threshold(divide, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow("blur", blur)
cv2.imshow("color_mask", color_mask)
cv2.imshow("divide", divide)
cv2.imshow("binarized_gray", binarized_gray)
cv2.waitKey(1)

# Define custom config for better or

# The digits is a config file that just defines the possible characters as 01233456789
custom_config = r"--psm 8 digits"

cv2.imshow("result image", binarized_gray)
cv2.waitKey(1)

# Do the ocr
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(binarized_gray, lang='eng', config=custom_config)

print(result)
```

I tried:

- different lower/upper values
- enlarging the image
- using different models, including one specifically for digits
- different psm modes

Answer (score 0):

Better you can go with easyocr.I had tried OCR for the raw images that you given above without any preprocessing.

```
import easyocr
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'], gpu=False)
result = reader.readtext('2.png')
for detection in result:
    print(detection)
```

the output for first image is,

```
([[169, 1], [286, 1], [286, 37], [169, 37]], '161441', 0.744929857940604)
```

the output for second image is,

```
([[106, 0], [141, 0], [141, 32], [106, 32]], '91', 0.7728322907607116)
```

You can install **easyocr** by `pip install easyocr`. I hope this will helpful for you.

Comment: Sadly I cannot use easyocr in my project, because it installs a version of opencv which is not compatible with other packages in my project.

Comment: which version of opencv that you working on?

Comment: Version 4.6.0 and I needed to compile it myself

Answer (score 0):

You can go with keras-ocr then

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras_ocr

pipeline = keras_ocr.pipeline.Pipeline()

images = [
    keras_ocr.tools.read('/content/1.png')
]

prediction_groups = pipeline.recognize(images)
for i, data in enumerate(prediction_groups):
    print(data)
```

the output for first image is

```
[('161', array([[174.,   4.],
       [222.,   4.],
       [222.,  34.],
       [174.,  34.]], dtype=float32)), ('441', array([[231.,   5.],
       [285.,   5.],
       [285.,  34.],
       [231.,  34.]], dtype=float32))]
```

the output for second image is

```
[('91', array([[109.,   3.],
       [140.,   3.],
       [140.,  29.],
       [109.,  29.]], dtype=float32))]
```

This doesn't cause opencv-python conflicts.

Comment: yeah.. sorry for that.  My bad